# Java input stream and buffer to php

Tags: java, php

How can we write this from java in php?

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))
```

I was looking around and found some things:

```
$handle = fopen('file', 'r');
$content = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);

$input = stream_set_read_buffer($content, 256);
```

Is this correct? Or is there better way?

I am trying to re-write this in php :/

https://github.com/nayuki/Reference-arithmetic-coding/tree/master/java/src

Comment: Well have you tested it? If you get the same results as in java then it's probably going to be ok (depending exactly how you tested)

Comment: @ADyson I did but it aint it, seems like InputStream.read() in Java reads byte by byte from a file so if I want to do same I would need to use fread() after fopen() with params as fread($handle, 1) // 1 as one byte, then put that into while loop and use: 
`while (!feof($handle)) {
    $byte= fread($handle, 1);
}` or am I wrong?

Comment: Well are you wanting to replicate the exact behaviour, or just the outcome?

Comment: well if using buffer and byte by byte reading is faster, i would like to do same in php instead of loading whole file in memory at once..